# How to return a default image url if the generated image url is not available in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular...

```
$scope.imageUrl[0] = 'images/' + $scope.repos[i].name + '.png';
$scope.imageUrl[1] = 'images/placeholder.png';

$scope.repos[i].imgSrc = (Utils.isImage($scope.imageUrl[0])) ? $scope.imageUrl[0] : $scope.imageUrl[1];
```

Utils.isImage() is from the following factory:

```
app.factory('Utils', function($q) {
return {
  isImage: function(src) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var image = new Image();
    image.onerror = function() {
      deferred.resolve(false);
      return false;
    };
    image.onload = function() {
      deferred.resolve(true);
      return true;
    };

    image.src = src;

    return deferred.promise;
   }
 };
});
```

The image url is generated from an api response object. I'm using Utils.isImage() to check if the generated image url exists in the images folder on  the server.
But the (Utils.isImage($scope.imageUrl[0])) is still true even if the image is found on the server or not found.
How can I fix this?

Plunker link - [portfolio](http://plnkr.co/edit/9mpNErg64hapcl4Of1hU?p=info)

Comment: what is that Utils? I would make this on server side  - server should know what images it has.

Answer (score 0):

The `Utils.isImage` function return a **promise** so is always `true`.

Angular use the `$q`service to provide asynchronous functionality. ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q))

To correctly handle the promise you should use at least the `then()` function and provide callbacks for a **resolved** or **rejected** promise.

```
Utils.isImage($scope.imageUrl[0])).then(
   function() {
      // Here is true  
      $scope.repos[i].imgSrc = $scope.imageUrl[0]
   },
   function() {
      // Here is false
      $scope.repos[i].imgSrc = $scope.imageUrl[1]
   }
)
```

Comment: I get this error after implementing the then function:
  TypeError: Cannot set property 'imageSrc' of undefined
  at Utils.isImage.then.$scope.repos.(anonymous function).imageSrc (http://localhost/portfolio/js/controllers.js:54:38)

Comment: here's the link to my plunker files - http://plnkr.co/edit/9mpNErg64hapcl4Of1hU?p=info

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply write a directive something like this:

```
myAppModule.directive('noImageIcon', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var defaultURL = attr.defaultURL || 'images/plaecholder.png';

            attr.$observe('ngSrc', function(newValue) {
                if (!newValue) {
                    element.attr('src', defaultURL);
                } else {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.onerror = function() {
                         element.attr('src', defaultURL);
                    };
                    image.onload = function() {
                    };

                    image.src = newValue;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now your image html tag will be like:

```
<img ng-repeat="repo in repos" ng-src="images/{{repo.name}}.png" />
```

Comment: How do I make use of the directive in the controller?

Comment: here's the link to my plunker files - http://plnkr.co/edit/9mpNErg64hapcl4Of1hU?p=info - you may take a look at it